# zip sets of tuples into set - python

Tags: python, set, tuples

If I have:

```
A = {(a,b),(c,d)}
B = {(b,c),(d,e),(x,y)}
```

I'm looking to create a new set with the first element from A and the second element from B when the other elements are the same:

```
C = {(a,c),(c,e)}
```

I've tried:

```
return {(a,c) for (a,b) in A for (b,c) in B} # nested loop creates too many results
```

and

```
#return {zip(a,c)} in a for (a,b) in A and c for (b,c) in B
#return {(a,c) for (a,c) in zip(A(a,b), B(b,c))}
#return {(a,c) for (a,b) in A for (b,c) in B}
```

These just don't work, I'm not sure I fully understand the zip() function.

Edit: had the example case wrong and added a condition, I need something like this:

```
return {(a,d) for (a,b) in A for (c,d) in B} # but ONLY when b == c
```

Comment: Your first expression works fine, but of course the order might be different, as it's an unordered set. What result did you get instead?

Comment: Sorry had it wrong, see the edit.

Comment: When you say `first element from A` and `second element from B` -- you realized that sets are unordered? so 'first' and 'second' how? Lexicographic sort will work (if the tuples are strings), but is that what you are after?

Comment: I mean the elements in the tuples contained in the set. I think the last line in the post says it well I hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your last attempt

> ```
> {(a,d) for (a,b) in A for (c,d) in B} # but ONLY when b == c
> ```

you almost got it. You just need to move the condition from the comment to the set comprehension:

```
>>> {(a,d) for (a,b) in A for (c,d) in B if b == c}
{('c', 'e'), ('a', 'c')}
```

Of course, the order is kind of random, since sets are unordered.

```
>>> {('c', 'e'), ('a', 'c')} == {('a','c'),('c','e')}
True
>>> {('a','c'),('c','e')}
{('c', 'e'), ('a', 'c')}
```

Comment: I had the OP wrong at first but edited it. For those A and B, the result should be {(a,c),(c,e)}

Comment: @RyleyLyon The result _is_ `{(a,c),(c,e)}`. Sets are unordered.